# Inheritance of same name method from difference traits

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, traits

I have a trait that extends two other traits that have the same name for a function but its a bit different from the inside, I want to know how do I know which function will be invoked?

I have trait `B` that has `print()`, and trait `C` that has `print()`, if I inherit both of them like this:

```
trait A extends B with C {
    def print()
}
```

each print printing something else, which print will be invoked?

Answer (score 7):

In the particular case where you have name conflicts, you'll receive a compile time error. Assuming `D` is the implementing class:

```
class D extends A with C with B

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val d = new D
  println(d.print())
}
```

You'll see:

```
Error:(25, 9) class D inherits conflicting members:
  method print in trait B of type ()Unit  and
  method print in trait C of type ()Unit
(Note: this can be resolved by declaring an override in class D.)
  class D extends A with B with C
```

However, If we help out the compiler by adding an `override print()` to `D`, and make it call `super.print()`, it will print the last trait in the linage which support a `print` method, i.e.:

```
trait A { }

trait B { def print() = println("hello") }

trait C { def print() = println("world") }

class D extends A with B with C {
  override def print(): Unit = super.print()
}
```

We'd get "world". If we switched `B` and `C`:

```
class D extends A with C with B {
  override def print(): Unit = super.print()
}
```

We'd get "hello".

Comment: I'd just add that you can be explicit: `class D extends A with B with C { override def print(): Unit = super[B].print() }`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important features of Traits in the original Schärli, Ducassé, Nierstrasz, Black paper is conflict resolution via renaming and hiding. This feature is completely absent from Scala's Traits.

In Scala, conflicts are simply not allowed. They are detected and rejected by the type system. (The original paper was in the context of Smalltalk, which doesn't have a type system, so a different approach was used.)

Answer (score 0):

Scala compiler gives you compile error.

Why don't you see it yourself using Scala REPL.

```
scala> trait B { def print(): Unit = println("B") }
defined trait B

scala> trait C { def print(): Unit = println("C") }
defined trait C

scala> trait A extends B with C { def foo = print() }
cmd11.sc:1: trait A inherits conflicting members:
  method print in trait B of type ()Unit  and
  method print in trait C of type ()Unit
(Note: this can be resolved by declaring an override in trait A.)
trait A extends B with C { def foo = print() }
      ^
Compilation Failed
```

I think you can easily understand using the compiler error